# Z-Index Layering issues where content is above the navigational dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm working on some HTML/CSS/JQuery to create a nice design, i have been working on some CSS dropdown navigational items yet the body content seems to be playing itself right on top of my dropdown menus. I've been trying to work with z-index in order to get the layering correct. But i just can't seem to get it right!

HTML Sidebar (navigation with dropdown)

```
<div class="ap-sidebar ap-sidebar-light ap-sidebar-fixed" id="ap-sidebar" role="sidebar">
      <div class="ap-sidebar-profile" role="profile">
        <div class="ap-sub-menu">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/profile.jpg" alt="Profile Avatar" /> <span class="user">mdixon18</span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/profile.jpg" alt="Profile Avatar" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
            <li class="seperator"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ap-bade">2</span> Un-Read E-Mails</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ap-bade">8</span> Assigned Tickets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ap-bade">23</span> New Post Comments</a></li>
            <li class="seperator"></li>
            <li><a href="#">View Profile</a></li>
            <li class="seperator"></li>
            <li>Not mdixon18? <a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

HTML Main (content that overlays the dropdown menu)

```
<div class="ap-content" role="Main">
 <div class="ap-header">
   <h1>Overlaying text!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (done with sass)

```
body .ap-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: $c2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
body .ap-sidebar-dark {
  background-color: $c5;
}
body .ap-sidebar-light {
  background-color: $c6;
}

body .ap-sidebar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 88px;
  line-height: 88px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8ed054;
}

body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu img {
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  @include border-radius(25px, 25px, 25px, 25px);
  top: 6px; /* (48/2) - 16 = 8 */
  border: 2px solid #65ad25;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu span.user {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  top: -62px;
  text-align: center;
}

body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu:hover > ul.dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 500;
}

body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu ul.dropdown li {
  float: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  height: 40px;
}

body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu ul.dropdown li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}


body .ap-sidebar .ap-sidebar-profile .ap-sub-menu ul.dropdown li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: $c5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body .ap-content {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I've included z-index's where i felt was necessary and tried others in places i was unsure about just to test but the HTML overlay heading text seems to be placing itself right on top of the dropdown menu even if i use something like `z-index: 9999;`. Can anyone notice my mistake?

http://jsfiddle.net/ggVas/ you can see the heading text overlaying the menu.

Thank you.

Comment: You have `z-index: 1` set for `.ap-content` and `.ap-sidebar`, so since `.ap-content` is styled after `.ap-sidebar`, it might be covering it up.

Comment: Wow it was really that simple! thank you for spotting that!!! really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @TylerH has spotted when you have two main containers if you assign them both with the same z-index then the last declared one in the DOM will take priority over the previous. Thanks for the help @TylerH.

Simply had to change `z-index: 1;` to say `z-index: 2;` on the `.ap-sidebar` class i hope this is useful to anyone else who has a similar issue.